# Order an association in Active Record to override default sort order defined in association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

So I have a class called agency and in that class I have the following:

```
class Agency
  has_many :users,  order: 'last_name ASC, first_name ASC'
end
```

And, when I do the following:

```
irb(main):004:0> agency.users.order('active desc').pluck(:active)
```

and that generates the following

```
  SQL (22.0ms)  SELECT "users"."active" FROM "users" WHERE "users"."agency_id" = 4040 ORDER BY last_name ASC, first_name ASC, active desc
```

So, what I want is to override the order in the agency class and not have it sort by last_name or first_name. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [***reorder***](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)

```
agency.users.reorder('active desc').pluck(:active)
```

The SQL generated would be

```
SELECT "users"."active" FROM "users" WHERE "users"."agency_id" = 4040 ORDER BY active desc
```

From the Guides,

> The reorder method overrides the default scope order, for example:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, -> { order('posted_at DESC') }
end

Article.find(10).comments.reorder('name')
```

The SQL that would be executed:

```
SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id = 10
SELECT * FROM comments WHERE article_id = 10 ORDER BY name
```

In case the reorder clause is not used, the SQL executed would be:

```
SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id = 10
SELECT * FROM comments WHERE article_id = 10 ORDER BY posted_at DESC
```